# PHP-Downloadscript - download limit doesn´t work

Tags: php

when i use this phpcode to download a file with a downloadspeed of 300Kb/s i use this:

```
 function readfile_chunked($dl_link, $filesize_file) {
  $chunksize = 300*1024; #Buffersize in Byte 
  $data = '';
  $handle = fopen($dl_link, 'rb');
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      $data = fread($handle, $chunksize);
      sleep(1);
      print $data;
      @ob_flush();
      @flush();
    }
  fclose($handle);
 }
```

But it doesn´t work! :-(

When i start the Download, the speed is under one KB/s and it breaks and then resume, and so on.

When i take off this "sleep(1)" in the code above, then the download starts and all is good, but it runs with fullspeed. -> logical!

Why is this?

Comment: Is `$dl_link` a local file? What is `$filesize_file`? Are you sending the correct download headers? Also, are you testing this from localhost or a proper server? Try removing the error suppression operator (`@`) to see if any error shows up.

Comment: If you have Linux, try doing `curl http://whatever/script.php`. It will reveal whether it is flushing the output buffer.

Comment: when i put `sleep(1)` after `flush()` then the speed is arund 8,5kb/s.

`$dl_link` is a remote file with a direct http download link from the another server.

`$filesize_file` is in this function only as information and does not any function in this code.

Comment: @MaxGunter: Yeah, then the problem must be `$dl_link`. Try specifying a local file and you'll see the true speed most probably.

Answer (score 2):

That looks mostly okay, however try the following:

```
function readfile_chunked($path, $speed)
{
    if (is_file($path) !== true)
    {
        exit('not a local file');
    }

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: public, no-cache');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    $handle = fopen($path, 'rb');

    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        echo fread($handle, $speed * 1024); sleep(1);

        while (ob_get_level() > 0)
        {
            ob_end_flush();
        }

        flush();
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

readfile_chunked('/path/to/your/file.ext', 300);
```

Comment: the downloadspeed is arund 8,0KB/s, with a local file, too. :-(

Comment: @MaxGunter: No idea then, try providing some more detail, perhaps a live URL we can test stuff on. Do you say the download pauses and resumes? That shouldn't happen with only those headers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding `@ob_flush_end()` at first to disable output buffering, and remove `@ob_flush()` in the loop. The delay may be because of the output buffering.

You may also try replacing `print` with `echo`. You may gain some performance improvement.

Also try a smaller chunk and use [`usleep`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) instead for a shorter delay time.

Comment: it doesn´t work, too. :(

try it here:
http://tinyurl.com/d62z9qr

and here the same code with NO `sleep(1)`:
http://tinyurl.com/c9tkekt

Comment: You see the delay of each chunk is 4 seconds... try my new suggestions?